# Java NIO 7-Zip FileSystem Provider

Tags: java, nio, 7zip

I've been trying to find a 7-ZIP FileSystem Provider for Java NIO, unsuccessfully. I'm a bit surprised that one does not seem to exist. Is anyone aware of one?

Comment: this will help maybe https://memorynotfound.com/java-7z-seven-zip-example-compress-decompress-file/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Compressing & Decompressing 7z file in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12781207/compressing-decompressing-7z-file-in-java)

Comment: Well, I'm specifically looking for NIO FileSystem implementation, not File-based solutions.