# Extracting XZ Compression

Tags: java, compression, xz

How do you extract an XZ file in Java? [I have a `7z SFX` file with an `.exe` extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35670707), [convert it into an `XZ` file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9186639/3764804) but how do I finally extract its contents?

On Windows, I can easily do an right-click and let [`WinRAR`](http://www.rarlab.com/download.htm) do the extraction by selecting `Extract here` from the context menu.

Answer (score 0):

try with this

```
try { 
    FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream(path + "myFile.xz");
    BufferedInputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(fin);
    FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(des + "myDecompressed");
    XZInputStream xzIn = new XZInputStream(in);
    final byte[] buffer = new byte[8192];
    int n = 0;
    while (-1 != (n = xzIn.read(buffer))) {
        out.write(buffer, 0, n);
    } 
    out.close();
    xzIn.close();
}
catch(Exception e) { 
    Log.e("Decompress", "unzip", e);
```

Comment: Not working, the decompressed file has a size of 0 bytes. I'm not developing for Android though